# Issue using shebang to run SBCL Common LISP script as executable

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, shebang

I've been trying to learn Common Lisp with SBCL and I've ran into issues executing my code. Everything works fine using `sbcl --script exec.lisp` (regardless of if I have specified a shebang line) but I can't seem to execute the same file with a shebang line directly as `./exec.lisp`. While I've most likely misunderstood something the [manual](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Shebang-Scripts) does from my understanding imply that this should be possible. My `exec.lisp` script looks identical to the one in the example (and it has been given executable privileges `chmod a+x exec.lisp`)

```
#!/usr/local/bin/sbcl --script
(write-line "Hello, World!")
```

but instead of the desired output I receive :

```
$ ./exec.lisp 
./exec.lisp: line 2: write-line: command not found
```

I've made sure that the path to `sbcl` is correct)

EDIT: I'm using mac OS.

Comment: What kind of machine are you attempting to run this on?

Comment: If Linux/UNIX, is the file marked as executable (`chmod +x`)? If Windows, is `sbcl.exe` in your system PATH?

Comment: Yep, that's what I was about to ask. If this is windows, you have to make sure to update your environment variables with the sbcl bin folder in order to run sbcl from the command line. This is a better question that can be answered with a tutorial however. You may also want to consider setting up an ide with emacs running sbcl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

had same problem on MacOS, changed to:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sbcl --script
```

worked.

Answer (score 4):

Using GNU Core Utilities on Arch Linux here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S sbcl --script
(write-line "")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check the path supplied for `sbcl` (does it match the output of `which sbcl` ?)

I tried the following (running MacOS Mojave 10.14.4, SBCL version 1.4.16, obtained using `nix` instead of `brew`, but I doubt that makes a difference):

```
> $ which sbcl
/Users/abrahma/.nix-profile/bin/sbcl

> $ bat test.lisp
───────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
       │ File: test.lisp
───────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1   │ #!/Users/abrahma/.nix-profile/bin/sbcl --script
   2   │ (write-line "Hello world from Lisp !")
   3   │
───────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

> $ l
.rwxr-xr-x 88 abrahma 21 May 15:54 test.lisp

> $ ./test.lisp
Hello world from Lisp !
```